# Redis key User Defined object vs String

Tags: java, redis

I  want to store , prefix with UUID in  redis as key.But it should occupy less memory. Which is the better way .
Below  are the different ways :

1) new object(prefix,uuid)

2) concat(prefix+uuid).

3) convert object to protobuff and storing it as keyr

Answer (score 3):

[Redis keys](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) are binary safe. So, it is best to store direct bytes of UUID rather than bytes of string representation of UUID. **UUID is 16 bytes, and lets assume your prefix is 4 bytes**. This is how your approaches stand out :

1) new object(prefix,uuid) : This would create a java object, but when storing, it would store the serialized form of the object, which would be much more than UUID+prefix bytes

2) concat(prefix+uuid) : This is the ideal approach, but you do not have to append prefix and uuid in string form. **Instead take a byte array for which first N bytes are for your prefix, and next 128 bits ( 16 bytes) are for the UUID.** Redis keys are binary safe, so your byte array becomes the key. This is the most memory efficient approach

3) convert object to protobuff and storing it as key : This would also store serialized format, with addition of datatypes info provided in protobuf, so not as memory efficient as 2.

**The best approach is (2), byte concatenation and storage as byte array key.**

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If we store key or value as byte array. Does it require to be base64 encoded? Because if we store it in  base64 encoding it increases approximately 100 bytes.

Comment: No. the java redis driver would take care of everything.

Answer (score 2):

It depends:

- If prefix+uuid length is small, say less than 30 chars. use concat.
- Otherwise for longer key lengths go with protobuf with gzip (if needed), like:

> ```
>   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>   GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
>   ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOut);
>
>   // Serialise object.
>   objectOut.writeObject(prefix+uuid);
>
>   gzipOut.flush();
>   gzipOut.close();
>
>   // save this byte[] as key
>   baos.toByteArray();
> ```

Comment: GZIP compression rather adds overhead if the payload is small.

Comment: Agree, that's why suggested to use only in case if longer keys.

Answer (score 1):

Byte accounting wrt to keyname size is important - keep em as short as possible.

That said, keep in mind that **each** key in Redis has an overhead (on top of the actual key name and value). While the exact overhead depends on architecture and version, having a lot of keys means a lot of overhead. One of the common ways to battle that is to use Hashes, as explained at https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis

Comment: thank you. I am using hashing. But still wanted to reduce the key size. so asked the above question